# Is it possible to show screen only once when app starts up?

Tags: android, database

I want to be able to prompt the users to enter the details required for the app only when it starts up for the first time (not other times). These details will be held in a database on the phone.

Would it be better to check the database each time or put these details in a shared preference? Furthermore, is this type of activity even possible on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the details really. If it is a large amount of information you might consider using a Database. For just basic identification information, SharedPreferences should be fine.

If you do use a Database, you might consider loading them into your Application object. This would depend on how frequently you use this information in your app.

To check for the first start of the app, a `SharedPreference` is generally used AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` or `Database` depending on the data complexity and its need later on..

Store a **Flag** in `SharedPreferences` and set this when user enters the data.

Check that shared preferences flag while on your first activity and redirects accordingly(to Details/one time page) if required.

here even if a user manually deletes data using Settings > Manage app > your app > clear data,  Your app will know to get the details then from user....